# Trello Webhooks request can not be verified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, trello, asp.net-webhooks

I created a mvc project with AspNetWebHooks TrelloReceiver (.net 4.5) and deployed it on appharbor. In the web.config I wrote the following:
`<add key="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_Trello" value="My Secret"/>`
And when the request comes, in the logs I see the following:

> The WebHook signature provided by the 'x-trello-webhook' header field
>   does not match the value expected by the 'TrelloWebHookReceiver'
>   receiver. WebHook request is invalid.

As a secret i'm using my Trello Oauth token. What could be the problem?